# Cannot use/update input value in react hooks which will be added to an image src attribute from a random image generator url

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have built a form with 2 inputs and I can get the input value using **react-hook-form** package but then i cannot update the state value with input value which i need to put inside an image src url end-point so that every time i submit the form i can get image width & height value and generate a random image. by the way i am using **Lorem Picsum** auto image generator but it's not working or i might be doing it wrong way and also getting error!..let me understand what's going on...Thank you very much.. :-)

[image]

// Here's the full code - no props coming from any other components

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const ImageGenerator = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const [firstInput, setFirstInput] = useState([]);
  const [secondInput, setSecondInput] = useState([]);

  const handleInput = (value) => {
    let firstValue = value.firstInput;
    let secondValue = value.secondInput;
    setFirstInput({ firstInput: firstValue });
    setSecondInput({ secondInput: secondValue });
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleInput)}>
        <div className="form-row">
          <div className="col-5 mt-4">
            <label htmlFor="firstInput" className="font-weight-500">
              Set Width
            </label>
            <input
              type="number"
              name="firstInput"
              className="form-control"
              id="firstInput"
              ref={register}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-5 mt-4">
            <label htmlFor="secondInput" className="font-weight-500">
              Set Height
            </label>
            <input
              type="number"
              name="secondInput"
              className="form-control"
              id="secondInput"
              ref={register}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-2 mt-5">
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="btn btn-primary"
              style={{ marginTop: "7px" }}
            >
              Generate
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div className="row">
        <img
          src={`https://picsum.photos/${firstInput}/${secondInput}`}
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default ImageGenerator;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why did you use array in useState()?

```
const [firstInput, setFirstInput] = useState([]);
const [secondInput, setSecondInput] = useState([]);
```

Comment: Sorry, i am new in react hooks i have no idea how i should use it properly. i am used to with class-based approach. Let me know the right way..thank you

Comment: I am also not very experienced but i think you should put zero in it rather than [] brackets because you want to pass an integer value to variable. right?

Comment: Yes...your idea actually works! but now iam facing another propblem...submit is still not working but random image coming in..which is a step ahead i guess...Thanks :-)

Comment: I have found it myself. Thank you for your help. because of your clue, I actually found a way...